# Android Studio file association for true-type font file

Tags: android, android-resources, truetype

When copying a true-type font file to the font resource directory in Android Studio 2.3.3, it asks to define the file association of a *.ttf file. However, there is no choice related to a true-type font. If no association is defined, the project errors when built. Which file association should be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use android studio 2, the font file must be under app\src\main\assets directory

Comment: Putting the *.ttf file in a "fonts" folder under the assets directory works.